# Unable to read resources via K8s API

Tags: curl, kubernetes, rbac

**UDPDATED**
I am trying to get resources via curl inside a pod deployed on K8s.
While I am able to fetch the list of pods via curl request, I can't on configmaps and nodes.

Here the Role Binding I am using (working for pods)

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: test-ro
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["pods", “configmaps”]
  verbs: ["get","list"]


 apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    kind: ClusterRole
    metadata:
      name: test-cro
    rules:
    - apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
      resources: ["nodes”]
      verbs: ["get","list"]
```

and when I try to fetch the list of nodes:

```
    curl -sSk -H "Authorization: Bearer $KUBE_TOKEN"       https://$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:$KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT/api/v1/nodes
        {
          "kind": "Status",
          "apiVersion": "v1",
          "metadata": {
            
          },
          "status": "Failure",
          "message": "nodes is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:test:test\" cannot list resource \"nodes\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "kind": "nodes"
  },
```

the same for configmaps:

```
curl -sSk -H "Authorization: Bearer $KUBE_TOKEN"       https://$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:$KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT/api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps
    {
      "kind": "Status",
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "metadata": {
        
      },
      "status": "Failure",
      "message": "configmaps is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:test:test\" cannot list resource \"configmaps\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"default\"",
      "reason": "Forbidden",
      "details": {
        "kind": "configmaps"
      },
      "code": 403
```

instead on pods it is working.
What could be the issue? A Wrong configuration on RoleBinding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give the `test-ro` Role access to list ConfigMaps, the resource name must be specified in its plural form. This is likely why listing Pods works, but listing ConfigMaps does not. So the Role should be specified like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: test-ro
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["pods", "configmaps"]
  verbs: ["get","list"]
```

Listing Nodes requires some different configuration due to Nodes being a cluster-level resource rather than a namespaced resource. [Due to this, the `nodes` permissions must be given in a `ClusterRole`.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole)

Additionally, the API url to list nodes does not have the namespace. The correct url would be `https://$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:$KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT/api/v1/nodes`.

An example of a working `ClusterRole` could be this:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: test-clusterrole
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["nodes"]
  verbs: ["get","list"]
```